# How to find out website protocol change date?

Tags: seo, web-development

Is it any way that I can find out the date my client changed the website protocol?

Comment: Did you ask your client when they did it?   What stats are available to you?  Google Analytics?  Google Search Console?  Other analytics?

Comment: They didn't take any backup. It was around 4 years ago. Isn't there any other way to figure it out?

Comment: No analytics going back that far?   Why do you want to know?   I can't imagine it matters at this point.

Comment: You mean website **content** and not protocol? Because a website protocol could be like switching from HTTP/1.1 to HTTP/2.0 or even if not technically 100% accurate, switching from HTTP to HTTPS. So please explain what you are writing about in more details.